# Using ShareKit without ActionSheet

Tags: sharekit

Anybody know to use the ShareKit framework without ActionSheet?
I don't want to use the buttons in ActionSheet. I'd like to use of way customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you have a problem. It does not work. The last line gives error.

```
-(IBAction)onClickFacebook:(id)sender;{
    NSLog(@"erro");
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ninja_crouch.jpg"];
    SHKItem *item = [[SHKItem alloc] init];
    item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"Look at this picture!"];    

    [SHKMail shareItem:item];    

}
```

Answer (score 2):

just create a sharekit item and start to share by using the choosen method, f.e. sharing by mail:

```
SHKItem *item = [[SHKItem alloc] init]; 
item = [SHKItem image:myUIImage title:@"Name of the image" ];
[SHKMail shareItem:item];
```

and don't forget to import the needed classes

```
#import "SHK.h"
#import "SHKMail.h"
```

Comment: -(IBAction)onClickFacebook:(id)sender;{
    NSLog(@"erro");
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ninja_crouch.jpg"];
    SHKItem *item = [[SHKItem alloc] init];
    item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"Look at this picture!"];    
    
    [SHKMail shareItem:item];    

}